# Regex to fetch all spaces as long as they are not enclosed in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, ecmascript-6, regex-negation

Regex to fetch all spaces as long as they are not enclosed in braces

This is for a javascript mention system

ex: "Speak @::{Joseph Empyre}{b0268efc-0002-485b-b3b0-174fad6b87fc}, all right?"

Need to get:

> [ "Speak ", "@::{Joseph
>   Empyre}{b0268efc-0002-485b-b3b0-174fad6b87fc}", ",", "all ", "right?"
>   ]

[Edit]

Solved in: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-http-8sgk2

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should expand your question adding with the current code is not working for you and provide more scenarios.

Comment: I think this type of regex may not be possible with JavaScript's regex implementation. You might be better off parsing the string yourself as opposed to using RegEx. I believe you'll need to use negative/positive look behinds/aheads, some of which aren't possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question as you said to `to fetch all spaces as long as they are not enclosed in braces`, although your result example isn't what I would expect. Your example result contains a space after speak, as well as a separate match for the `,` after the `{}` groups. My output below shows what I would expect for what I think you are asking for, a list of strings split on just the spaces outside of braces.

```
const str =
    "Speak @::{Joseph Empyre}{b0268efc-0002-485b-b3b0-174fad6b87fc}, all right?";

// This regex matches both pairs of {} with things inside and spaces
// It will not properly handle nested {{}}
// It does this such that instead of capturing the spaces inside the {},
// it instead captures the whole of the {} group, spaces and all,
// so we can discard those later
var re = /(?:\{[^}]*?\})|( )/g;
var match;
var matches = [];
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
  matches.push(match);
}

var cutString = str;
var splitPieces = [];
for (var len=matches.length, i=len - 1; i>=0; i--) {
  match = matches[i];
  // Since we have matched both groups of {} and spaces, ignore the {} matches
  // just look at the matches that are exactly a space
  if(match[0] == ' ') {
    // Note that if there is a trailing space at the end of the string,
    // we will still treat it as delimiter and give an empty string
    // after it as a split element
    // If this is undesirable, check if match.index + 1 >= cutString.length first
    splitPieces.unshift(cutString.slice(match.index + 1));
    cutString = cutString.slice(0, match.index);
  }
}
splitPieces.unshift(cutString);
console.log(splitPieces)
```

Console:

```
["Speak", "@::{Joseph Empyre}{b0268efc-0002-485b-b3b0-174fad6b87fc},", "all", "right?"]
```